# SQL with CASE: identify the existence of a value contained in a column of WHERE

Tags: sql, mysql

This is the first time I've created a SQL with `CASE`. I must have done something wrong with `WHEN` and `ELSE`.

I would like to obtain the condition that:

- If `team_away`....is contained in the `round` column which has `1`...and if `team_away` is contained in the `team_away` column....then it is OK
- If `team_away`....is contained in the `round` column which has `1`...and if `team_away` is contained in the `team_home` column....then it is NULL

Notice that `team_away=?` is both a variable and the column name

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT team_home, team_away, score_home, score_away 
FROM Results
WHERE

    (CASE
       WHEN current_round= 1 AND team_home = team_away=? THEN NULL
       ELSE current_round= 1 AND team_away = team_away=?
    END)

LIMIT 1;            
''', [Match_Team_Away, Match_Team_Away])
```

Maybe the problem is in the syntax setting: `AND team_away = team_away=?` or `team_home = team_away=?` (two =)

**UPDATE:**

This is table Result:

| current_round | team_home | team_away | score_home | score_away |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Liverpool | United | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | Arsenal | Aston Villa | 4 | 1 |

For example if my `team_away` variable (team_away=?) is `United`, it means it is in the `team_away` table as you can see. In this case I would like to use the second CASE (the one with ELSE). Whereas if `United` had been in the `team_home` table and not in `team_away`, then I would have liked to receive a NULL

Comment: Case statement in sql is as follows:
CASE 
    WHEN expression1 AND/OR expression2 AND/OR expression3.... THEN value1
    WHEN expression4 AND/OR expression5 AND/OR expression6.... THEN value2
     ...
     ELSE value
END as column_name

also find an alternate for double equal in single expression as it doesn't make sense to SQL

Comment: @Sam I don't understand much from the formatting of your code in the comment. Could you show me a solution using my values please?

Comment: @EvangelosDellas the question is unclear for multiple reasons. There are no variables in queries, but there may be parameters. `team_away=?` isn't a variable or parameter name, it's an equality check between `team_away` and a nameless parameter `?`. CASE is an expression that returns a value, not a way to group conditions. You can compare its return value to something else if you want, but that usually leads to bad performance. If you want to combine options, use `OR`. The evaluation order doesn't matter

Comment: You probably do not need to use `case when` in a `where` statement. `case when` is used to create a new column based on some conditions. `where` is used to filter. What do you want to do ? filter the lines or create something new ?

Comment: The conditions you describe are unclear too. `If team_away....is contained in the round column which has 1...and if team_away is contained in the team_away column....then it is OK` what does that mean? One column is contained in another? But both are equal to 1? Or a column is contained in itself?

Comment: Post sample and desired data and the logic. Don't try to explain the process. Right now you're using the wrong terms, confusing everyone. SQL is set based - you don't specify checks one after another, you specify a condition and the database will find the matching rows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos team_away=? with the question mark is a variable. team_away without a question mark is the column

Comment: Don't use `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause. Use regular `AND`/`OR` instead.

Comment: Also note that a [mcve] should contain _both_ sample table data _and_ the expected result.

Comment: @EvangelosDellas no, it's not a variable. There are no variables in a *query*, and that syntax doesn't exist in MySQL or any other SQL product. That's an expression comparing `team_away` with the positional parameter `?`.  `team_away = ?`

Comment: If you want to find results for a specific round and team, the condition would be `WHERE current_round =1 and (team_home = something or team_away = something)`.  That something differs based on the Python library you use. If you use [Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) you can use `WHERE current_round =1 and (team_home = %s or team_away = %s)` to pass parameters by position or `WHERE current_round =1 and (team_home = %(name)sor team_away = %(name)s)` to pass them by name

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using SQLite, so this syntax exists. I want to insert the team_away= parameter into the team_away... column?

Comment: You said you use MySQL. You used the `mysql` tag. That syntax doesn't exist in SQLite either, in fact [SQLAlchemy's parameter example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#sending-parameters) shows that the actual query uses `?`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They changed my question tags. It wasn't me

Comment: The very first version of the question has the `mysql` tag, not `sqlite`. Even if you use SQLite, parameters are passed as `?`, as [the SQLite3 examples show](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). `WHERE current_round =1 and (team_home = ? or team_away = ?)`

Comment: The can [also be passed by name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries) `WHERE current_round =1 and (team_home = :team or team_away = :team)`